# MYSQL - Full text match against fail for 'NA'

Tags: mysql, match-against

I have this DB (MySql v5.7)

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test3_sim;
CREATE TABLE test3_sim (
ID INT not null,
texto VARCHAR(1024)
);

ALTER TABLE test3_sim ADD FULLTEXT(texto);

INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (1,'NA');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (2,'NA');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (3,'DUPLICATE');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (4,'OTH');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (5,'NOP');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (6,'NOP');
INSERT INTO test3_sim (id,texto) VALUES (7,null);
```

I'm performing some search via fulltext syntax in BOOLEAN MODE, searching for different value match.
I cannot really figure it out why it fails when I search for term 'NA':
This query resoult is empty:

```
SELECT id, texto
FROM test3_sim
WHERE MATCH (texto) AGAINST ('NA' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
AND texto is not null
```

But it should output first 2 rows.

All works fine for 'DUPLICATE', 'OTH', 'NOP' search.

Is there a specific reason why query is failing?
Demo here

Comment: Without addressing your specific issue, I will observe that it's difficult to test FULLTEXT on such a tiny data set.

Comment: FULLTEXT has a default `ft_min_word_len` setting off 3, meaning it will not index strings with a length which are less.

Answer (score 0):

As per @Raymond Nijaland comment it's due FULLTEXT has a default ft_min_word_len setting off 3, meaning it will not index strings with a length which are less